# Can I reload the profile for a running ipython notebook/jupyter server? If so, how?

Tags: configuration, jupyter-notebook

I've started moving from older ipython notebook servers to jupyter (aka ipyton 3) and occasionally forget to update the profile with new things specific to jupyter (e.g.: `save_script` alternative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351623/420867)). There some kernels running and would prefer not to have to restart them to activate the profile changes.

Is there a way to do that with a live server? Can I access the servers `get_config()` (as used in the profile file) from a notebook or in some other way? Or perhaps some other way to add a post-save hook?