# Export a notebook (.ipynb) as a .py file upon saving

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm currently working with Jupyter IPython Notebook.I would like to put my notebook under version control.

That's why, when I save and checkpoint a Notebook (.ipynb file), I would like the changes to also be saved and synchronized in the corresponding python script (.py file) in the same folder. (see picture below)

[my_files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAgiY.png)

Does it have something to do with the version of Jupyter I am using? Or do I have to edit a config_file?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create jupyter_notebook_config.py in your config-dir.

if doesn't exists, execute below command from home directory : 
    ./jupyter notebook --generate-config

Add paste following code in this file :

```py
import os
from subprocess import check_call

c = get_config()

def post_save(model, os_path, contents_manager):
    """post-save hook for converting notebooks to .py and .html files."""
    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return # only do this for notebooks
    d, fname = os.path.split(os_path)
    check_call(['ipython', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'script', fname], cwd=d)
    check_call(['ipython', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'html', fname], cwd=d)

c.FileContentsManager.post_save_hook = post_save
```

You will then need to restart your jupyter server and there you go!

Comment: This seems correct to me : some more details about this little config script can be found here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329667/ipython-notebook-script-deprecated-how-to-replace-with-post-save-hook

And for curious minds, here is the original issue topic on github :
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8009

Comment: In new versions of jupyter you will get warning: _"Subcommand 'ipython nbconvert' is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. You likely want to use 'jupyter nbconvert' in the future."_ Thus substitute `ipython` for `jupyter` in the code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351623/286795

Comment: jupytext works. https://towardsdatascience.com/introducing-jupytext-9234fdff6c57