# Jupyter Lab auto nbconvert to python setting?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

On my work computer I set Jupyter Lab to auto-convert notebooks to python .py, so both the notebook and .py script are autosaved.

But having installed Jupyter Lab on my home computer, strangely I don't see that setting or option.

I also conda installed nbconvert in case it's a required package but that didn't help.

Comment: You don’t say how you set JupyterLab to do that prior. Was it something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020524/8508004)?

Comment: @Wayne, prior to JupyterLab I used Jupyter Notebook, which required that nbconvert hook. But I don't remember, if, once I swtiched to Lab, whether that script is still in effect - somehow I remember a setting or option, but can't find it.

Comment: @Wayne, for example Jupyter Lab has Export Notebook As... item in File menu that includes to Executable Script (.py). I don't think that requires nbconvert installation.

Comment: I saw [this version of that hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57752513/8508004), too. And [this question](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/adding-a-post-save-hook-with-an-extension/3230) being under the JupyterLab category a few weeks ago at the Jupyter Discourse Forum suggests a [.post_save_hook](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/savehooks.html) still works for JupyterLab.