# Converting all files in folder to .py files

Tags: python

I was wondering if their is anyway to go through and make copies of each .ipynb file in a folder and then change that file to .py. I want to keep the .ipynb files but I would like to have a .py file as well. I know how to do it manually but would like a way to do it automatically for each file in a specified directory.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797709/convert-json-ipython-notebook-ipynb-to-py-file) out, I think it'll help

Answer (score 5):

Just try this at Cmd prompt inside that folder.

```
jupyter nbconvert *.ipynb --to script
```

Converts all .ipynb files to .py and retains all .ipynb files as well.

Hope it helps

For more details, Check this link as well [Save .ipynb to .py automatically on saving notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329667/ipython-notebook-script-deprecated-how-to-replace-with-post-save-hook)

Answer (score 4):

`find . -name "*.py" -exec ipython nbconvert --to=python {} \;` should work on Linux.

Comment: exec does not work

Answer (score 4):

```
import os

directory = 'ipynb PATH'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.ipynb':
            exe_command = 'jupyter nbconvert "{}" --to python'.format(''.join(os.path.join(subdir, file)))
            
            # print the command`enter code here`
            # print (exe_command)
            
            os.system(exe_command)
            
            # Delete the file 
            # os.remove(''.join(os.path.join(subdir, file)))
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Converts all .ipynb files in a directory  to .py you can delete the files that been converted, you should pip install nbconvert before

Comment: amazing solution- helped to convert all my ipynb into py

Answer (score 0):

To convert all .ipynb files to .py in a directory structure recursively you may execute

```
find . -name "*.ipynb" -exec jupyter nbconvert --to script {} \;
```